# gradle fails to resolve dependency via nexus proxy repository

Tags: maven, gradle, nexus

I'm new to nexus (and maven for that matter). I'm in the process of migrating an existing nexus config to a new server and am having a little issue. It is serving local artifacts fine, When gradle tries to resolve this particular dependency it fails to locate the artifact. The it resolves just fine against the old repository. Both the old and new repositories are configured as proxys

```
> Could not resolve org.jboss.ws.native:jbossws-native-jaxrpc:3.0.4.GA.
  Required by:
      xxx.xxx:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT > org.jboss.ejb3:jboss-ejb3-ext-api:1.0.0 > org.jboss.javaee:jboss-ejb-api:3.0.0.GA
> Could not find any version that matches org.jboss.ws.native:jbossws-native:3.0.4.GA.
```

now, the confusing bit.

The new repo is a proxy and uses the exact settings that the old one uses. I can browse the new repo in nexus and see the offending artifact. I can also search for it by artifact name it is is found fine. The only difference i can see between the 2 is that the old repo has a cache of the remote artifacts and the new one has yet to cache anything

Here is the relevant config (same on both)

```
type: proxy
Provider: Maven2
Format: maven
Policy: Release
Default Local Storage: file:///home/nexus/sonatype-work/nexus/storage/jboss
remote storage location: https://repository.jboss.org/
Download remote indexes: True
Auto Blocking Enabled: False
File Content Validation: True
Checksum Policy: Warn
(no auth set up)
Not Found Cache TTL: 1440
Artifact Max Age: -1
Metadata Max Age: 1440
Item Max Age: 1440
```

any tips would be awesome, i'm going a little mad

Comment: argh, think i found the issue. Seems like artifacts were being addressed via a group and that group was not including the proxy repo ...